# Unable to determine a button is disabled with native android automation/Java

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am performing some appium automation on a native android app and I am stuck with the following situation:

I have a login button which has the following characteristics (see screenshot attached). Now no matter if the login button is enabled or disabled, those characteristic you see in the screenshot don't change. This is a problem as I want to test that the login button is disable based on certain text entry criterias.

I am unsure if something else is driving the login button where it is enabled or disabled (by the way whether the button is enabled or disabled, it visually looks the same).

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can tackle this? If I cannot do anything in regards to checking the button, the only thing I can think of (if it is possible) is to somehow determine after I click the login button that I remain on the same page (maybe wait for no retry message to be displayed as well as checking the login button remains on the page).

Thanks[image]

Comment: currently appium cannot detect if the button is enable or disable. So the only solution i see is to click the button and check if it remain in the same screen to verify if button is disable.

Comment: Cool, so is there a fancy way of checking not in another screen or simply look at some elements on the page like login button, login title and a username field?

Comment: if you are using **Page Object Model**, it will be easy for you to check screen is changed. you can implement some method like **isScreenDisplayed()**. `public boolean isScreenDisplayed(){      try {      if(element.isDisplayed) {          return true;     }else {return false;} 
       }catch(Exception e){        return false;   }}`

Comment: Awesome, thank you Suban

Comment: If that is helpful, you can upvote the comment.

Comment: Did you find way to check if button is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Appium does support this kind of check: [element/:element_id/enabled](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/enabled/#example-usage)

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByResourceId("login_submit");
boolean isEnabled = element.isEnabled();
```

If still always returns you the same result I suggest checking the source code of your app to make sure property is set properly. It is much better to fix the App for testability instead of the hacky check by clicking.